# Use solution relative packages folder with NuGet and project.json

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package-restore, project.json

I have a solution with a `packages` folder checked into source control. I changed some of the projects to use a `project.json` file rather than `packages.config` for defining dependencies. The projects are all normal `.csproj` projects, not DNX `.xproj` projects. Everything seemed to be working correctly however after updating a package I noticed that the new version wasn't added to the solution's `packages` folder. Instead it was added to NuGet's new shared packages folder in the user profile folder.

So the question is, how do I get NuGet to use the solution's `packages` folder rather than the shared folder?

Approaches I've tried so far without success:

- Adding `global.json` file in the solution folder specifying `"packages": "packages"`
- Setting `<add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="false" />` in `.nuget\nuget.config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NuGet 3.2](https://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-3.2) added support for specifying the shared global packages folder using an environment variable, `NUGET_PACKAGES`. You can set the full path to an alternative global packages folder, however I discovered that if you simply set the variable to "packages" then the NuGet tools in Visual Studio will treat it as a relative path under your solution folder. That allowed me to install and restore NuGet packages using the solution's `packages` folder.

Unfortunately building projects then gave me errors in `Microsoft.NuGet.targets`, unable to locate NuGet packages. The `NugetPackagesDirectory` property in msbuild doesn't seem to getting set. To work around this I added the following lines in to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.props` file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(NugetPackagesDirectory)' == ''">
  <NugetPackagesDirectory>$(SolutionDir)packages</NugetPackagesDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This will affect all solutions on the machine so an alternative would be to add those same lines in each project file or into a custom `props` file in the solution which you import into each project. This may also be needed for build servers too.

Although this works, the drawback is that the packages folder has a different structure, `packages\<package_name>\<version>\` compared to `packages\<package_name>.<version>\`, and old or unused versions of packages aren't deleted after they're updated or uninstalled. Manually clearing the packages directory and then restoring required packages after any changes will achieve the same thing.

Personally this feels really hacky as it requires setting global settings for something which should be set on a per solution basis. NuGet is going to be updated at some point to support per solution package directories with `project.json` but in the meantime this you can use the above work around, or just stick with `packages.config` for the time being.

Comment: Another alternative is to pass `/p:NuGetPackagesDirectory=c:\my\new\dir\ ` on the command line when you call msbuild (assuming you have called `nuget restore -PackagesDirectory c:\my\new\dir\ `

Comment: "NuGet is going to be updated at some point to support per solution package directories with `project.json`..."

Do you happen to have a GitHub issue or other URL you can cite for this? I searched around on NuGet's GitHub issues and couldn't find anything about this.